# Updating value in firebase removes children

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My app has a user profile and a wish list both of them are saved on firebase

**[The tree of firebase used]**

[image]

The problem is when a user changes his/her country, gender, or name the whole WishList child is removed automatically I still don't know why, so can you guys help? 
These are snippets of my code:

The method to update proflie in Profile activity:

```
public void updateProfile() {
    String name = editName.getText().toString().trim();
    String country = countriesSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String gender = genderSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

    UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo(name, country, gender);
    databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).setValue(userInfo);
}
```

Adding items to WishList in other activity (Products information stored in local database):

```
 Button wishListBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.wishListBtn);
    wishListBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                final FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                final String key = databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).child("WishList").push().getKey();

                final WishlistItem wlItem = new WishlistItem();
                wlItem.setwId(key);
                wlItem.setwName(cursor.getString(1));
                wlItem.setwStore(cursor.getString(2).toUpperCase());
                wlItem.setwCategory(cursor.getString(3));




                databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).child("WishList").orderByChild("wName").equalTo(cursor.getString(1)).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if( dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                            //Value exists
                            Toast.makeText(ProductDetails.this, "Already added to Wish List", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        } else {
                            //Value doesn't exist
                            databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).child("WishList").child(key).setValue(wlItem);
                            Toast.makeText(ProductDetails.this, "Product Added successfully to Wish List", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using

```
databaseReference.child(user.getUid())
                 .setValue(userInfo);
```

you override the whole node.

You can either do (as an example)

```
databaseReference.child(user.getUid())
                 .child("uCountry")
                 .setValue(country)
```

or you add another child to the userId like `userInfo` which contains country, gender,name and do

```
databaseReference.child(user.getUid())
                 .child("userInfo")
                 .setValue(userInfo);
```